# how to keep ionic from refreshing page when using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic3, angular-components, angularfire5

i making a counter when everytime a users click a button it substracts 1 from the counter updates the node in firebase then return this change via another method with .valuechanges.subscribe
but everytime this happens it refreshes the whole page deleting all user inputs.

```
constructor(private dd: PlayerInfoProvider, private strge: Storage, private ss: Slot2machineProvider, private slotProvider: SlotProvider) {
    this.slotProvider.getTries(this.dd.getCurrentUser()).valueChanges().subscribe(snapshot => this.gettries(snapshot));
  }

  gettries(snapshot) {

    // this.playerObject = snapshot;

    this.tries = snapshot;
  }

  runSlots() {

    if (this.tries <= 0) {

      alert("you cannot play anymore sorry!! but if you want you can purchase some more luck");
    } else {
      this.slotOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
      this.slotTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
      this.slotThree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
      this.slotFour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
      this.slotFive = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;

      // this.sloty1 = '<p > "' + this.slotOne + '"</p>';
      // this.sloty2 = '<p > "' + this.slotTwo + '"</p>';
      // this.sloty3 = '<p > "' + this.slotThree + '"</p>';
      // this.sloty4 = '<p > "' + this.slotFour + '"</p>';
      // this.sloty5 = '<p > "' + this.slotFive + '"</p>';

      if (this.slotOne !== this.slotTwo || this.slotTwo !== this.slotThree) {
        this.loggerr = "<h2>sorry try again.. </h2>";

        this.playerObject.tries = this.tries - 1;
        //alert("you only have " + this.playerObject.tries + " chances left ");

      //  this.ss.substractTries(this.dd.getCurrentUser(), this.playerObject);
      } else {
        this.loggerr = "<p>jackpot!!!</p>";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: ok thank you very much